# Joomla and (not default) positions

Tags: html, css, joomla, web

I am trying to transfer my simple website to joomla. I like the design and style I did in html5/css3, but I think that the content management is something that I could take advantage of. I have my design, so I decided to give templates a go.

I understand how on the templateDetails.xml you defined the locations:

```
<positions>
    <position>breadcrumb</position>
    <position>right</position>
    <position>top</position>
    <position>footer</position>
</positions>
```

But I don't understand how can I create a new position. For example if I wanted to create a position on the bottom right below the main content or even more specific where should this information go? I see this are the default positions http://docs.joomla.org/Module_Map.

The idea I have right now is to do my template with all the div tags, that I already have but just erase the content and then in the content create a a div tag where I put

```
<div id="content" class="float"> <jdoc:include type="component" /></div>
```

But then I don't think I am really taking advantage of joomla.

Or whats a better way to move a html/css3 website to joomla without having to use a template (I have not liked any 100%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="bottom_right" style="xhtml" />` will allow you to add the position to the index.php of your template. Then you can assign a module at the backend. Don't forget to add `<position>bottom_right</position>` to the XML of your template.

If you need to clarify anything please raise your question here

Comment: My question is how does it know what bottom_right means? Does it map bottom right with absolute position/relative, and if so where can I change it? If I want bottom_right to be on the top, is there a file I should change?

Comment: we define bottom_right in the XML saying that it is a position

Comment: I think I had the wrong concept. In your index.php, the <div id="content" class="float"> <jdoc:include type="component" /></div> set the location of the "position" and then I use joomla to do the rest. Meaning index.php defines the locations. I am just plain stupid i think